# Métodos de clase

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo

El código que adjunto define una clase con una serie de métodos y objetos **pero mi duda es que debe** añadir un método de clase(@classmethod) llamado "cambio" para actualizar o añadir la tasa de cambio para una moneda, cuyo código se pasa cómo string, con un valor float pasado cómo segundo parámetro.

```
    class Currency:
    """Represents an amount of euros and
       can give its equivalent valor in other currencies
    """
    __exchange_ratio_cambios = {
        "EUR" : 1.0,
        "JPY" : 124.83,
        "USD" : 1.11918,
        "GBP" : 0.85806
    }

    @classmethod
    def ratio_cambio(cls, currency):
        """Returns exchange ratio_cambio for currency or None"""
        if currency in Currency.__exchange_ratio_cambios:
            return Currency.__exchange_ratio_cambios[currency]
        else:
            return None        

    def __init__(self, valor = 0):
        """"valor is an amount of euros """
        self.valor = valor

    @property
    def valor(self):
        """"valor is an amount of euros """
        return self.__valor

    @valor.setter
    def valor(self, valor):
        """"valor is an amount of euros """
        self.__valor = valor 

    def convert_to(self, currency):
        """Returns the equivalent valor of self in another currency
           currency: currency to convert to 
        """
        ratio_cambio = self.__cls__.ratio_cambio(currency)
        return ratio_cambio if ratio_cambio == None else self.valor * ratio_cambio

if __name__ == "__main__":
¡
```

Comment: Tu duda es por qué se agrego el decorador de `@classmethod`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dado que las tasas de cambio se definen mediante el atributo de clase `__exchange_ratio_cambios` que es un diccionario, bastaría con algo así (incluyendo una validación mínima de los argumentos):

```
@classmethod
def cambio(cls, code, value):
    if not isinstance(code, str) or len(code) != 3:
        raise ValueError("code must be a string of length 3 ")
    if not isinstance(value, (int, float)):
        raise ValueError("value must be int or float")
    cls.__exchange_ratio_cambios[code] = value
```

Algunas observaciones:

- Es aconsejable usar `cls` para acceder a atributos de clase dentro de un método de clase en vez de usar el nombre de la clase. si en un futuro cambiamos el nombre de dicha clase nos evitamos modificar nada más.
- En Python la forma apropiada de comprobar si un objeto es `None` es usando el operador de identidad (`is`), no el operador de igualdad (`==`). Es decir, en vez de:

  ```
  if ratio_cambio == None
  ```

  sería

  ```
  if ratio_cambio is None
  ```
- Si quieres obtener el valor de una clave en un diccionario si existe o un valor por defecto si no existe, en vez de usar un condicional es más eficiente y simple usar `dict.get`. En vez de:

  ```
  if currency in Currency.__exchange_ratio_cambios:
      return Currency.__exchange_ratio_cambios[currency]
  else:
      return None
  ```

  puedes simplemente hacer:

  ```
  return cls.__exchange_ratio_cambios.get(currency)
  ```

---

```
class Currency:
    """Represents an amount of euros and
       can give its equivalent valor in other currencies
    """
    __exchange_ratio_cambios = {
        "EUR": 1.0,
        "JPY": 124.83,
        "USD": 1.11918,
        "GBP": 0.85806
    }

    @classmethod
    def cambio(cls, code, value):
        if not isinstance(code, str) or len(code) != 3:
            raise ValueError("code must be a string of length 3 ")
        if not isistance(code, (int, float)):
            raise ValueError("value must be int or float")
        cls.__exchange_ratio_cambios[code] = value

    @classmethod
    def ratio_cambio(cls, currency):
        """Returns exchange ratio_cambio for currency or None"""
        return cls.__exchange_ratio_cambios.get(currency)

    def __init__(self, valor=0):
        """"valor is an amount of euros """
        self.valor = valor

    @property
    def valor(self):
        """"valor is an amount of euros """
        return self.__valor

    @valor.setter
    def valor(self, valor):
        """"valor is an amount of euros """
        self.__valor = valor

    def convert_to(self, currency):
        """Returns the equivalent valor of self in another currency
           currency: currency to convert to
        """
        ratio_cambio = self.ratio_cambio(currency)
        return ratio_cambio if ratio_cambio is None else self.valor * ratio_cambio
```

> ```
> >>> c = Currency(43)
> >>> c.convert_to("USD")
> 48.12474
> >>> c.ratio_cambio("USD")
> 1.11918
> >>> c.cambio("USD", 1.13)
> >>> c.convert_to("USD")
> 48.589999999999996
> >>> c.ratio_cambio("USD")
> 1.13
> ```